# Get a special type of child in an xml document with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm looking for a way to get a special type of child out of a xml file with php.
the xml:

```
<notify type="post" name="Max" />
```

I want to grab the name out of there.
My code: `$sender =

```
    $sender = $node->getChild('notify');
    $sender = $sender->getChild('name');
    $sender = $sender->getData();
```

but as i expected it isn't working that way.
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: `name` is an attribute, not an element, nor a child. `$node->getAttribute('name')` is worth a shot, though: what did you use to parse the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `xpath` expression to get the job done. It is like an SQL query for XML.

```
$results = $xml->xpath("//notify[@type='post']/@name");
```

Assuming the XML in `$xml`, the expression reads like

```
select all notify nodes, 
where their type-attribute is post,
give back the name-attribute.
```

`$results`will be an array, and my code example is made for `simplexml`. You can use the same `xpath-expression` with `DOM` though.

Here's the complete code:

```
$x = <<<XML
<root>
    <notify type="post" name="Max" /> 
    <notify type="get" name="Lisa" /> 
    <notify type="post" name="William" /> 
</root>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($x);
$results = $xml->xpath("//notify[@type='post']/@name");
foreach ($results as $result) echo $result . "<br />";
```

Output:

```
Max
William
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/eO29FK

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately that doesn't work with my node (i don't know why. Its an Whatsapp message) $nnode->getAttributes works fine for my example, but with the second line of the xml it doesn't work anymore `<message from="49xxxx@s.whatsapp.net" id="message-1381085708-3" type="chat" t="1381085708"` in this case i want the from. but when i use the method getattribute i get the error: `Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object`

Comment: What exactly does not work with your node? Please edit your question, post a valid snippet of your XML, describe what didn't work with the solution i offered, and we'll try to support you.